# converting db2 datestamp to Unix timestamp

Tags: db2, unix-timestamp

How can  i convert 2012-04-12 00:00:00 to a unix timestamp in DB2. is there any inbuild function available in sql s

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Using the `DAYS` and `MIDNIGHT_SECONDS` is much more precise than `TIMESTAMPDIFF`:

```
SELECT
86400*(DAYS(CURRENT TIMESTAMP - CURRENT TIMEZONE)-DAYS('1970-01-01'))
+ MIDNIGHT_SECONDS(CURRENT TIMESTAMP - CURRENT TIMEZONE)
"UNIX_TIMESTAMP"
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

Answer (score 3):

By `Unix timestamp` I assume you mean the number of seconds (or whatever) since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.

There is no built in functionality for this in DB2 (as of V6R1).
You're also up against the following issues:

- All timestamps in DB2 are 'local time' - they contain no timezone information, and all `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` writes are based on what time the *requesting* system thinks it is, **not** the host.
- Daylight savings time changes frequently.  You would need to add overhead to manage this for your conversion.
- The `TIMESTAMPDIFF` function returns an *estimate*, **not** an exact value.  You could probably survive for the years/months durations, over sufficient differences, but days aren't likely to cut it.
- Timestamp arithmetic is imprecise (among other things, months are assumed to be always 30 days in length...)

Your best bet will be to start using `DAYS` (which returns the number of days since 0001-01-01).  Keep in mind you better do everything in UTC, because it will **not** take DST into account.